# Overleaf - Downloaded pdf shows lines on figure that are not visible in the png

Tags: pdf

I have this .png figure

[image]

When I upload it to overleaf with the following code

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth,trim={0.05cm 0.2cm 0 0},clip]{figures/intro.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{}
\label{fig:intro}
\end{figure}
```

And then download the pdf of my paper I see this in the figure now.

[image]

How do I tell latex not to render the lines ? Example

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth,trim={0.05cm 0.2cm 0 0},clip]{figures/intro.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\do_not_render_lines
\caption{}
\label{fig:intro}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: latex has no control  or access to the png data. you are scaling with `width=` and I assume this is making artifacts in the png more visible.Try scaling/cleaning the image in an external tool, then include it without scaling

Comment: Apparently the figure has been created using boxes and grouping of objects. Usually that information is not visible when exporting to vectorial `*png` format, but still present for edit purposes. LaTeX recompiles that vector information in creating the PDF outcome. Best option is to use a graphics conversion program like `XNView` (open source) to covert the `png` file to a `jpg` file and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: You **can** tell \includgraphics to trim off the outer 1pt or so.

Comment: @alchemist png is a bitmap not vector format

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue either. But artifact is the most likely reason.